# Problems modifying/deleting signers on envelope based on template REST API

Tags: python, docusignapi

I having trouble modifying or replacing the signer on an envelope based on a template. The template specifies 1 signer and 1 cc. The envelope is in a 'sent' status. The documentation indicates I can update some attributes for a signer who has not yet signed.

When I attempt to modify the signer (for example to update an email address) I get an error:

```
{
    u'recipientUpdateResults': [
        {
            u'errorDetails': {
                u'errorCode': u'RECIPIENT_UPDATE_FAILED',
                u'message': u'**Therecipientcouldnotbeupdated.Recipientislocked.**'
            },
            u'recipientId': u'1'
        }
    ]
}
```

I then tried the approach of adding an additional signer with the same signer role and then deleting the original signer.  When processing the delete I get another error:

```
{
    u'signers': [
        {
            u'errorDetails': {
                u'errorCode': u'RECIPIENT_DELETE_FAILED',
                u'message': u'**Therecipientcouldnotbedeleted.Recipientisrequired.**'
            },
            u'recipientId': u'1',
            u'routingOrder': u'',
            u'status': u''
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't understand what makes a signer locked or required. Is there some way I can release these restrictions to be able to do the modification or replacement?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Neither of the properties sender_can_delete or sender_can_edit were set on the template. I corrected the settings on the template and now the recipient modify and recipient delete work as intended via the REST api.

In the API response to get recipient status there are two key/values that indicate the lock status of the signer:

```
u'templateLocked': u'true',
u'templateRequired': u'true'
```